# How to create indexes on sub-documents in MongoDB via .NET

Tags: .net, mongodb, indexing

Is there a fluent syntax to create an index on the "author" key of the "reviews" sub-document of the "product" document, like how I would create an index on the "price" key?

```
var connStr = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connStr);
var db = client.GetDatabase("store");
var col = db.GetCollection<Product>("products");

await col.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Product>.IndexKeys.Descending(x => x.Price));
await col.Indexes.CreateOneAsync("{'reviews.author':1}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you are referring to is that the following doesn't work:

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Product>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Reviews.Authors));
```

It gives a compile time error.

Apparently we missed this scenario when we designed the IndexKeysBuilder. I've created a JIRA ticket to track adding this feature:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1340

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: thanks robert! we will wait for updates from this ticket.